# Fix the ambient Temperature in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, temperature

I successfully made an app to measure the ambient temperature in Android studio. But the next step doesn't want to work. here's the point:

- when I start the app the temperature should be shown in 1 textView (works so far). Then it should stay with this temperature but it changes. I only want to check the temperature once.
- when I click on submit it shall do the same with the second textView.

I did this successfully with the time but with the temperature, it won't work. And my second question is, I did a lot of research and it looks like the temperature will always be shown in °c. Can I change that so the people who want it in °F can have it this way?

Code for the temperature without change the value and with the button for getting the temperature on textView2:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private TextView textView, textView2;
    private Button button;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor tempSensor;
    private Boolean isTemperatureSensorAvailable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) !=null) {
            tempSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
            isTemperatureSensorAvailable = true;
        }else{
            textView.setText("Temperature Sensor is not available");
            isTemperatureSensorAvailable = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(isTemperatureSensorAvailable){
            sensorManager.registerListener(this,tempSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if(isTemperatureSensorAvailable){
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
    }

    private void update_text_unit()//Run from button
    {
        boolean toogle = false;
        float temperature = 0;
        float C_temp = 0;
        float F_temp =0;
        //Get sensor data
        Sensor temp = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
        F_temp = (C_temp * (9/5) +32);//Convert to °F
        if(toogle = true) {
            textView2.setText("Temp is:" + C_temp + "°C");
            toogle = false;
        }
        else {
            textView2.setText("Temp is:" + F_temp + "°F");
            toogle = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me going into a better direction.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the button temp change feature not exactly sure how you read the temp so the line of Sensor.gettemp will probably need to change. Run this from a button push, it will update your text view

```
private void update_text_unit()//Run from button
    {
        boolean toogle = false;
        float temperature = 0;
        float C_temp = 0;
        float F_temp =0;
        //Get sensor data
        C_temp = Sensor.gettemp();
        F_temp = (C_temp * (9/5) +32);//Convert to °F
        if(toogle = true) {
            yourtextview.setText("Temp is:" + C_temp + "°C");
            toogle = false;
        }
        else {
            yourtextview.setText("Temp is:" + F_temp + "°F");
            toogle = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much. do I see it right that the temperature this way is in °C except the user want it different? sorry try to understand the code. So i would have to do that for the first textview too right? and the button should work for humidity too true? i mean if i use the other sensor of course

Comment: I cant tell you about the text views as I dont know what you want them to display. For humidity you would need to get the humidity reading, then add the reading command(API) to the button code to set the value to another textview.

Comment: The target was to get kind of a diary. when i open the app it shall put me the actual temperature in TextView1. when i click on the button to finish the entry it shall put the actual temperature on TextView2. I am fighting with your help for the button atm. meanwhile it doesn't even show the temperature anymore when i start the app.

Comment: So you have a button in your xml with an ID. This is then linked to your activity via a reference. Then in your oncreate list a callback function. From there run the code to get the temp / pressure and set it to the UI

Comment: I changed the code up there. And added the XML so you know what i mean

Answer (score 2):

In the first code you have a section which is on sensor changed so this will run each time causing your issue. In you oncreate all the API to get the temperature once and chuck it to the text view as a string. For °C to °F you will need to convert. I would just do this manually:

`(X°C × 9/5) + 32 = result_°F`

Where X is the input temperature and result is the output in °F.

Comment: Thanks for your Help. Does that mean I cant say the code if the user want to use °C he has it in °C and in °F if he wants that? How can I just get the temperature once? Mean that it doesn't change again?

Comment: To just get temp once remove the update code aka the onsensor changed line. ```public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        //textView.setText(sensorEvent.values[0]+ "°C");
    }``` And yes you can specify the in the code if its C or F. You can do this via a button callback.

Comment: I tried to fix the code like you told me. Did I understand it right? The button still don't work but it looks like it is closer now. Thanks so much for your help Thomas. You're great